# Trace Flash Builder compiling commands

Tags: actionscript-3, terminal, flash-builder, mxmlc

is there a way to trace the compiler command for flash builder? I mean, I want to know the parameters and files that is compiling internally when I click "build" on FB.

Basically I moved a project to Flash Builder, and everything works fine but I have some runtime issues, and looks like the compiler is doing something wrong with some files (like using old files instead of using the one im changing, this occur only for a particular file, the rest works fine or I think that works fine). Also is different the way to embed some file, that's another reason to check what's doing internally.

I ran the game with mxmlc before, and probably I can compare what's the difference if I get the command executed by FB.

Also, I want to know how to do it if I need to research something in future.

Thanks for any help,

Regards

Comment: In all my years of AS3 programming i have never once needed to look at what the compiler did to my project. It will not "cache" files on you. More likely then not you are the cause of the issue. You said you moved to flash builder but didn't say from where.

Comment: I moved a project form flashDevelop to Flash BUilder. The problem is that this game has a lot of thing, it's not easy as move the code. There are a lot of libraries, embed assets, swc files with assets, compiling constants, and more things. As I said, it works fine, I work with flash builder since more than 1 year, and this is a particular problem that I couldn't fix yet and probably I can find something if I understand the difference between compiling the game in FD and FB. I also consider a problem between the air/flex versions that Im using on both projects, but Im still researching...

Comment: That is my point. the compiler isn't the issue. You have a setting somewhere that you missed. Or not pointing to a library. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I have runtime errors, I was working a few day on this. I know that probably I can fix my problem with a config, or something else through Flash Builder IDE, but I have to lose so much time. i.e. all the swc are working fine, but just one of them cannot convert a MovieClip to xxxx object when something happen on the game, the same swc works fine on flash develop. Another example, I have configuration files coming form server side, and then they are parsed and I should receive a Vector.<MyObjectXXXX>, but I get a Vector.<Object> instead...

Comment: ... So, my question is to make things faster just comparing both compilation parameters instead of being a long time researching and trying to find a way to fix it through FB.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder only recompiles if there has been a change to the code. So if you are changing an asset (image), for example, you won't recompile unless you also make a change to the project.

There are a few ways around this:

1. Easiest way is to just go into a file and press the space bar at the end of a line. It will add an extra byte to your file, but not to the project (compiler is "smart" and gets rid of unused files, classes, and characters). Since this is not a common thing, it shouldn't be an issue
2. `Project->Clean...`. That will force your workspace to rebuild and, in most cases, will also recompile your project
3. If #2 is failing, first delete `bin-debug` or whatever you are using as your debug folder, then run `Project->Clean...`

It's a tad bit annoying (especially when editing external libraries), but it allows for quicker re-launches of the debugger, which is the ultimate goal of that behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Anyway I know that, and I used all that before I create this post. Anyway, after doing all that, I have the same result, also I add a try.. catch on the line where I have the runtime error and I have the same result, look like it's not compiling the file. Also I checked if it's compiling the same file, and I don't have another one with the same name on my computer. Im not sure exactly what's wrong, Im thinking that I have another error not related with that line, and the debugger is pointing to a wrong line.